# Returning false not working with MVC post

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC view,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction","MyController",FormMethod.Post))
{
<input type="submit" id="submitSelectedItems" value="Add to Items" />
}
```

Also I have a Jquery onclick event for the submit button,

```
$a("#submitSelectedItems").on("click", function () {
            if (SelectedItem.length <= 0) {
                alert("Please select a style to proceed!!");                    
                return flase;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
            return flase;                
        });
```

Here I am successfully getting the alert when ever there is no items selected, however after the alert eventhough I am returning false, here the post to the action method is not stopped, it continuous with that? How can I stop posting? I even tried with `e.preventDefault();`, but no luck.

Comment: Is `flase` an actual typo in your code or just in this post?

Comment: Spelling mistake in 'flase'.

Comment: Also `$a` might be `$('a`?

Comment: How could I miss that :) $a is $a = jQuery.noConflict();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `flase;` Please check your code once again. It should return `false`,

```
$a("#submitSelectedItems").on("click", function () {
        if (SelectedItem.length <= 0) {
            alert("Please select a style to proceed!!");                    
            return false;    //you have spelled wrong false as flase
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
        return false;     //you have spelled wrong false as flase           
    });
```